# ModelForm Not Showing in Template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

For some reason (excuse my newbieness with django) my template is not displaying my form, I currently have:

**view**

```
def Scan(request):
    form = SubmitDomain(request.POST or None) # A form bound to the POST data

    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        if form.is_valid(): # If form input passes initial validation...
            form.cleaned_data['domainNm']  ## clean data in dictionary
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/processing/')

    else:
        form = SubmitDomain()

    return render(request, 'VA/index.html', {
        'form' : 'form'
    })
```

I read on [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template) to use `{{ form.as_p }}` to display the `<input>` of the form, but it isn't showing. Is something glaringly preventing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing an `string` as `form` not the `instance` of `SubmitDomain`
change this:

```
 return render(request, 'VA/index.html', {
    'form' : 'form'
})
```

for this:

```
 return render(request, 'VA/index.html', {
        'form' : form
    })
```

Comment: Great point - this seemed to resolve it. Lesson learned. Thanks!

Comment: Give SO 10 mins to allow me to and I will - had already tried :)